# How to pass input type object from Pact (typescript) to GraphQL mutation

Tags: typescript, graphql, pact, mutation

Creating Pact consumer/provider test against GraphQL mutation which has input type as query parameter.

GraphQL schema:

```
input ReviewInput {
  stars: Int!
  commentary: String
}
```

GraphQL mutation:

```
mutation Stars(
  $input: ReviewInput!
) {
  createStars(input: $input) {
...
```

On Pact's consumer side (using typescript), I have to define query variables which are expected to be passed to GraphQL mutation. 
If I only define variables `stars` and `commentary`, trying to start test from Pact's provider side results with an error that input type variable is not defined.

Pact consumer side:

```
describe('Stars', () => {
    describe('with correct variables', () => {
      const variables = {
        stars: 1,
        commentary: 'test',
      }
```

Pact provider side error:

```
"message":"ReviewInput isn't a defined input type (on $input)"
```

How should I define input type on Pact's side which would include `stars` and `commentary` and pass that input type to GraphQL mutation?

Hope someone can help and thank you!

Comment: Could you please add the pact file that has been generated, and, ideally, a full reproducible example? That will help us investigate.